# MYSQL: UPDATE tblUser SET userName = 'MD5 hash generated version of the userName' WHERE userID IN (...)?

Tags: mysql

Im trying to update a userName field in my database to a MD5 hash generated version of that persons userName. I have to do this to a lot of users so I was wondering if anyone out there has a quick mysql update query that will handle this, or if I should just write a function that will take care of it.

Something along theses lines:

UPDATE tblUser SET userName = 'MD5 hash generated version of the userName' WHERE userID IN (...)

Any thoughts?

Comment: @ClydeLobo I imagine because he might "write a function that'll...", but it's unnecessary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`MD5()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5) function.

```
UPDATE tblUser
SET userName = MD5(userName)
WHERE userID IN (...);
```

Comment: Yeah this was the first thing I tried but it didn't work. Not sure why... Same query works if I replace the MD5(userName) with MD5('test') which is strange.Nevermind. This did work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in md5() of mysql

```
UPDATE tblUser SET userName = md5(userName) WHERE userID IN (…)
```